# how to check the coulmn null in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i have a table with 3 columns

```
id,  params                  ,  xml 
1,   $pmn=67676$tns=67678787$=pro ,<ConsentDTO><OrderId>76676</OrderId><ReceiverInformation>              <ReceiverType>SMS</ReceiverType><CellPhoneNumber>78787</CellPhoneNumber></ReceiverInformation></ConsentDTO>
```

i have written two query to return phone number from params and Xml colums 
in params column  value with tns=67678787 is phone number
in XML cplumn value in node CellPhoneNumber is pone number

params

```
select SUBSTRING(params,  
   CHARINDEX('$tnr=',params) + 5,   
   CHARINDEX('$pro',params) - CHARINDEX('$tnr=',params)-5) from table1
```

XML

```
select table1.xml.value('(/ConsentDTO/ReceiverInformation/CellPhoneNumber/text())[1]','varchar(50)') from table1)
```

now my question is if the params column doesn't have phone number means other query should execute .

can you help me use condition statements?

Comment: use ISNULL()  operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view and use a CASE...WHEN Statement for the field. Something like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN params IS NULL THEN '' ELSE params END) as params FROM Table1
```

Then use this view to do your conversions. Hope this help.

Comment: actually can you put the above query in the place

Comment: because if the param don't have value it should check XML column

Answer (score 0):

Use the exist() on your XML column in the WHERE clause of your query.  This will limit the results to records with XML content that contains the desired content.

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE xmlColumn.exist('/Path/to/data') = 1;
```

Comment: Should check params query return if its null then execute second statement , to get value from xml column